# Is it possible to return any one conditional that are true out of multiple ones (in a simple way)?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, if-statement, ecmascript-6

This has likely already been answered multiple times, but I am unable to find any good answers. I'm probably not searching for the right things..

I have a number of checkboxes that return "on" or "off".

req.query returns these checkboxes.

If they are "on" I would like to push that particular key/val pair to an array for later to be used in a query in mongoDB. I know I can use Object.entries(req.query)to loop through them, but I just want to know if there might be another way like the example below.

```
let checkboxCol = [];
if (checkboxa, checkboxb, checkboxc, checkboxd) {
    checkboxCol.push(/* any checkbox that is "on" */);
}
```

Comment: `checkboxes.filter(c => c).first()` or `checkboxes.some(c => c)`

Answer (score 3):

Use `filter`:

```
let checkboxCol = Object.values(req.query).filter(({ isOn }) => isOn);
```

If your property is called something different, swap it for `isOn`, and if the value is not a Boolean, add a comparison operator - it may look like this:

```
let checkboxCol = Object.values(req.query).filter(({ on }) => on == "on");
```

Comment: Turns out this wasn't exactly what I needed, although it was helpful.

If I do:

`if (checkboxa || checkboxb || checkboxc || checkboxb){
 console.log(req.query)
}`

it returns {checkboxa : "on"}, if this was the checkbox i ticked.